# wordpress do_action without add_action and action hook names

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I kind of understand add_action and then do_action. for example

```
function mywork()
{
    echo "display my work";
}
add_action('mytag','mywork',10);
do_action('mytag');
```

this will render "display my work";

But how about just do_action only. 
for example

```
function customfunction()
    {
        echo "custom";
    }
do_action('customfunction');
```

Nothing is rendered.
I also found some wordpress api hook names. for example "login_form"

```
do_action(login_form);
```

But nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `do_action("actionName");` you are creating a hook, so you can write code that will be executed here from external sources.

So, you can write `do_action("actionName")`, but since you have not added code to execute when this `do_action()` get called it will do nothing.

When you write `add_action("actioName","functionName",parameters)` you are telling to WordPress: "*Hey, whenever you make a call to `do_action("actionNAme")`, execute `functionName`*"

**Update**

Answering to this comment:
"But can I do `do_action` without any `add_action` first or callback functions?".

The answer is No, you can't.  You have created the hook, but you need to attach code to it somewhere or it will do nothing, this is like an event, with `do_action` you are telling: "*Hey, this happened*". With `add_action` you are telling when happen run that function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do u mean do_action hook will not work if there is no callback function added by add_action. I have to do add_action first? Do add_action first and then do do_action, I understand this already. But can I do do_action hook without any add_action first or callback functions like in my second example. In second example I have written a code for "customfunction" to execute and then I called do_action(customfunction). So all wordpress defined hooks have done add_action first. I hope u understand what I am saying. I will reply more later or tomorrow.

Comment: In your update answer, "attach code to it somewhere", do u mean attach code by add_action callback. If it is, is that the only way?

Comment: yes, it is the only way, do_action and add_action are apair, they work together, the one is meaningless without the other